# MATLAB - array2table nesting

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

For the purpose of simplicity I'll try to take an example from everyday life. Let's say I have a table in CSV file loaded in a table called **dataOriginal** with 3 columns - names, jobs , dates.

Let's take a closer look at the column "date":

```
date
____
'13.01.2014 20:34'
'22.03.2014 11:17'
...
```

I want to split date in a date-vector and add this vector (along with the variable names for each of it's columns (since we have multiple dates we have de facto a matrix)) to a column in a new table again named "Date" but with all the naming goodies in it such as year, month etc.

---

Here is what I have done so far (sorry for the poor code quality but I've just started learning MATLAB :-/):

1. I split each date in a date-vector and also add names to each element like this:

   ```
   dateFormat = 'dd.mm.yy HH:MM';
   [year,month,day,hour,minute,second] = datevec(datesRaw, dateFormat);
   ```

   so that I have this:

   ```
   year(1) % returns '2014' since this is the first date in my column
   year % returns all years in my entire column
   ```
2. Then I converted the above to a table:

   ```
   dates = array2table([year,month,day,hour,minute,second],'VariableNames',{'year','month',...,'second'});
   ```

   so I get a nice output like this

   ```
   year   month       second
   ____   _____  ...  ______
   2014     1            0
   2014     3            0
   ...    ...   ...    ...
   ```

   This allows me an easy-to-read access to each column by simply calling for example:

   ```
   year % returns all years
   year(1) % returns first entry's year (here: '2014' from '13.01.2014 20:34')
   ```
3. I've processed my other columns too doing various operations on those and at the end I'm trying to horizontally concatenate all like this:

   ```
   name              job                   date
   ____    _____________________  _____________________
                                  year month ... second
                                  ____ _____     ______
   "Bob"   "Construction worker"  2014   1   ...   0
   "Alice" "Waitress"             2014   3   ...   0
   ...              ...            ...  ...  ...  ...
   ```

I'm struggling exactly with the part with the nesting of year,month etc. in a single column named "date". I'd like to address a date's element in the table above as follows:

```
myData.name(1) % will return 'Bob'
myData.job(1) % will return 'construction worker'
myData.date(1).year(1) % should return '2014' for Bob, the construction worker
```

Currently I'm having the following code after some sweating and swearing:

```
dataFinal = 
    horzcat(array2table([dataProcessed(:,1),dataProcessed(:,2)],'VariableNames',[dataOriginal.Properties.VariableNames(1),dataOriginalProperties,VariableNames(2)]],
    array2table([year,month,day,hour,minute,second],'VariableNames',{'year','month','day','hour','minute','second'}))
```

where

- dataProcessed(:,1) are my processed names
- dataProcessed(:,2) are my processed jobs
- dataOriginal.Properties.VariableNames(1) is the name of the first column in my original table - "name"
- dataOriginal.Properties.VariableNames(2) is the name of the second column in my original table - "job"

I do not know how to insert

```
array2table([year,month,day,hour,minute,second],'VariableNames',{'year','month','day','hour','minute','second'})
```

in a named column "date" in order to accomplish my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, it may be what you're looking for:

```
data = table(names, jobs, table(years, months, ...), 'VariableNames', {'name', 'job', 'date'})
```

Though you will address as follows, which is slightly different from what you said you want; it may still work for your purposes:

```
data.name(1);
data.job(1);
data.date.year(1);
```

EDIT: To see your output, do

```
disp([data(:, ~strcmp(data.Properties.VariableNames, 'date')), data.date])
names    ids    years    months
_____    ___    _____    ______
'Bob'    1      2014     4     
'Max'    2      2013     8
```

(when editing the comment I didn't exactly replicate the data and fields from the answer, but I think you should get the point here).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast reply. The way the addressing works is much better (data.date.year(1)). I wrote it my way because I was presuming that this is how it works. Your code however returns the error "The VariableNames property must contain one name for each variable in the table.

Error in table (line 304)
            t = setVarNames(t,vnames); % error if invalid, duplicate, or empty"

Comment: Never mind. I had 2 table() calls inside the main table without variables but as you have pointed out there is no need for those. It is working perfectly!!! Thank you so much! One last question though - is it possible to make MATLAB actually produce the same output as I have imagined in my original post? Rigth now under the "Date" column the console is simply displaying a [1x6 table] for each date element. I'd like to also see inside that nested table but when calling the big table. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Edited comment to give you something similar but not exactly the same.  Getting the display exactly as you specified above would require a custom function, I think.  It could probably be a fairly simple function that employed some clever recursion to handle the table of tables in the date column.